# Sorting a Mongo cursor such that certain documents Ids come first

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Mongo collection that I need to search, returning the results sorted as follows:

- first by whether or not the document id is present in an array that I pass in.
- then by another field in the document.

My use-case is that the user has a set of 'favourited' items that I wish to display first in the list. I'm storing that list of ids in the user's document.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I could only see this being done with two queries, first to find the ones that the user has favourited and the next for the entries that are not favourited, sorted by the field that you want.  But perhaps somebody else has another way.

Comment: Can't be done in the database (in a single query). Either retrieve data in two parts (as suggested by challett) or sort in the app.

Comment: You could use a hook to change a boolean on the collection you're returning so that when one is favourited, it gets marked. Then use `{$sort: {favourite: -1, other_field: 1}}`

Comment: I've used two queries, and that works well. The disadvantage is that Meteor now has more work to do maintaining two separate queries per client.

Answer (score 0):

As @Challet suggested above, with the addition of templating to avoid having to concatenate the two search results and keeping both lists reactive in the process:

**html:**

```
<template name="myTemplate">
{{#each favorites}}
  {{> detail}}
{{/each}}
{{#each nonFavorites}}
  {{> detail}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="detail">
... layout details here ...
</template>
```

**js:**

```
var idsOfFavorites = []; // however you maintain this

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  favorites: function(){
    return MyCollection.find({ _id: { $in: idsOfFavorites }},
      { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}); // sorting by createdAt but could be any field
  },
  nonFavorites: function(){
    return MyCollection.find({ _id: { $nin: idsOfFavorites }},
      { sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
  }
});
```